# shell script: Indirect recursion doesn't work as expected (too many repetitions)

Tags: bash, function, shell, recursion

I'm working on a BASH shell script using Pashua for dialogs. Now I have come to a structural problem: My main function starts with a dialog getting user input. Then it calls a function to test this input. If this turns out satisfactory nothing happens and main continues. If it's not, the test function returns an error and calls main again so that the user can do things right this time.
This leads to the parts in main after calling the test function run twice (or even more) as well. Which is not desirable but understandable.

Example:

```
main () {
    ...do some dialog stuff...
    test_function
    ...do some more interesting stuff...
}

test_function () {
    if [ ...something doesnt fit... ]
    then
        echo "lets try this again!"
        main
    fi
}

main
```

So, how can I prevent the script from executing *...the more interesting stuff...* more then once? Like breaking out of main and start main again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give up the recursion.
It doesn't belong in such a case.

```
main () {
    while ! read_input; do
        echo "lets try this again!"
    done
    ...do some more interesting stuff...
}

read_input () {
    ...do some dialog stuff...
    [[ ...something doesnt fit... ]] && return 1 || return 0
}


main
```

Comment: +1, but would be better to do `while read_input && test_successful` or `while read_input && ! test_failed` ... and get the call to main out of `test_successful`.

Comment: Also, compressed both functions into one after that suggestion.

Comment: This does indeed seem like an elegant solution and I'll test it asap. Thanks! But I did some more thinking on my own and now I wonder if it would work to simply  put an "exit" on the end of the main function. That would be easier to implement. Or does it have downsides?

Comment: You know what, I think it'll work, but it's weird to have a mandatory exit on a 'main' function cause it can be called several times. A recursive solution is not something this kind of problem begs for, and it really over complicates things.
Moreover, It might be easier to implement it like this **now** given the current code, but I think that the suggested solution will be a lot more comprehensive when revisiting the code (or when reviewed by someone else).

Comment: Another downside i thought of is adding another input. It's really hard with the recursion, cause the main always **re**-starts from the first variable (and what if the second input is bad). on my suggested solution it's very easy to add another input test. all you need is another while and another read_input. So, it's also **scalable** compared to the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop over the dialog code with a flag not to skip the first iteration if needed:

```
main () {
    local first=1
    while [[ $first ]] || test_function ; do
        dialog_stuff
        unset first
    done
}

test_function () {
    if [ ... ] ; then
        return 1
    fi
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main () {
    while do_some_dialog_stuff; do
        test_function && break
    done
    ...do some more interesting stuff...
}

do_some_dialog_stuff() {
  ...do some dialog stuff...
  return 0
}

test_function () {
    if [ ...something doesnt fit... ]
    then
        echo "lets try this again!"  >&2
        return 1
    fi
}

main
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the input stuff and test stuff together so you can return the overall status with one function.  This makes sense since you'll always want to run test stuff after input stuff.

Then, you can run a loop over a single function.  I find `until` more readable than `while !` when waiting for something to be correct.

```
main (){
    until test_function; do
        continue
    done
}

test_function () {
    ... do some dialogue stuff ...
    if [ ...something doesnt fit... ]
    then
        echo "lets try this again!"  >&2
        return 1
    fi
}
```